# Colon in a lambda function?

Tags: haskell, lambda

I don't understand the role of the colon in the following lambda expression:

```
myFunction :: [Int] -> [Int]
myFunction li = foldr (\x acc -> if x < 10 then x : acc else acc) [last li] li
```

I'm used to seeing the colon for recursive actions, however it looks like this colon is effectively saying **prepend** to current accumulator list, is that right?

Comment: It's actually a prepend, not an append.

Comment: That's the list notation *<head : tail>*. Not much to do with the lambda.

Comment: it might be a bit clearer with redundant parentheses, `(\x acc -> if (x < 10) then (x : acc) else acc)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:` is a data constructor. It prepends a value of type `a` to an existing (possibly empty) list of type `[a]`.

```
let x = 1 : [2,3,4]  -- x == [1,2,3,4]
```

You can picture the list type constructor as being defined like this:

```
data [] a = [] | a : [] a     -- : as an infix operator
data [] a = [] | (:) a ([] a) -- : in prefix positino
```

which might read more easily as

```
-- [] == List
-- (:) == Cons
data List a = EmptyList | Cons a (List a)
```

By "recursive action", I assume you mean you see it being used in a pattern matching situation like

```
head (a:as) = a
```

This is not unique to `(:)`; pattern matching can be done with *any* data constructor.